# Map/Merge Dataframe Values Vertically and Create Additional Index in Multi-index Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I am new to non-horizonal merging and multi-index pandas operations, and have been experiencing trouble solving this problem. I have a multi-index pandas dataframe with 'Region' as the top level index and 'Pet' under that:

```
Region:    Region1  Region1  Region2  Region2
Pet:       Cat      Dog      Cat      Dog
0          1        8        5        9
1          4        3        7        1
```

I am looking to map the following dataframe to create a third index, 'Kind', below 'Pet':

New dataframe:

```
    Pet  Kind
0   Cat  Tabby
1   Dog  Weiner
```

Objective dataframe:

```
Region:    Region1  Region1  Region2  Region2
Pet:       Cat      Dog      Cat      Dog
Kind:      Tabby    Weiner   Tabby    Weiner
0          1        8        5        9
1          4        3        7        1
```

I have looked into vertical merging with no success. I may also not have the correct language to describe my problem while searching the web. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) to add an extra header row to our dataframe. We will also be converting the new_df `Pet and Kind` to [`dictionary by zipping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) the column so that it becomes easier to iterate through our Multi-Index tuple and add extra value of `Kind` to our Multi-Index tuple by doing a simple lookup.

##### Creating the data

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Region1','Region2'],
                                     ['Cat','Dog']],
                                    names=['Region','Pet'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 8, 5, 9], [4, 3, 7, 1]],
                  index=[0, 1],
                  columns=header)

Region  Region1   Region2    
Pet     Cat Dog   Cat Dog
0       1   8     5   9
1       4   3     7   1

new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Pet' : ['Cat', 'Dog'],
    'Kind' : ['Tabby', 'Weiner']})
```

I hope you have your data until this point.

##### Generating output

```
newdf_dict = dict(zip(new_df.Pet, new_df.Kind))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(a, b, newdf_dict.get(b)) for a,b in df.columns], names=df.columns.names + ['Kind'])
```

##### Output :

This gives us the expected output :

```
Region       Region1        Region2       
Pet        Cat    Dog     Cat    Dog
Kind     Tabby Weiner   Tabby Weiner
0            1      8       5      9
1            4      3       7      1
```